# Herokuのメモリ使用量について教えてください

Tags: heroku

HerokuでRailsアプリを稼働させているのですが、メモリの使用量はどのように確認すれば良いでしょうか？ ダッシュボードで確認できるのでしょうか？

現在は無料枠で使用しており、容量が512MBのため有料プランへの変更を検討しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hobby dyno以上にしたら Apps > アプリケーション > Metrics から見られるようになります。

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/metrics

> Application metrics are only available to apps that are using hobby, professional (standard-1x, standard-2x and performance), or private dynos. Applications using free dynos do not have access to application metrics.

Comment: ありがとうございます！プランをhobby以上に変更します。